# Joining two tables with common fields by using a third table with same primary key

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I am trying to create a join between 3 tables 2 of the table share mostly of the fields (just a couple of them are different) I would like to know how can I create this join merging the common fields in just one column leaving in null/blank those not common when not data is present.

```
table 1:

PK1 geom field 2 field 3 field 4 field 5
1    1-1     1-2     1-3     1-4     1-5    
2    2-1     2-2     2-3     2-4     2-5   
3    3-1     3-2     3-3     3-4     3-5   
4    4-1     4-2     4-3     4-4     4-5   
5    5-1     5-2     5-3     5-4     5-5   

table a:

    PK1 field 1ab field 2ab field 3ab field 4ab field 5a
    1    1-1a       1-2a         1-3a     1-4a     1-5a     
    2    2-1a       2-2a         2-3a     2-4a     2-5a     
    3    3-1a       3-2a         3-3a     3-4a     3-5a      
    4    4-1a       4-2a         4-3a     4-4a     4-5a      
    5    5-1a       5-2a         5-3a     5-4a     5-5a
  

table b:

    PK1 field 1ab field 2ab field 3ab field 4ab field 5b field 6b
    6    1-1b       1-2b      1-3b     1-4b        1-5b      1-6b
    7    2-1b       2-2b      2-3b     2-4b        2-5b      2-6b
    8    3-1b       3-2b      3-3b     3-4b        3-5b      3-6b
    9    4-1b       4-2b      4-3b     4-4b        4-5b      4-6b
    10   5-1b       5-2b      5-3b     5-4b        5-5b      5-6b
```

RESULTING TABLE JOINING TABLE 1 PK:

```
PK1  geom    field 2ab field 3ab field 4ab field 5a field 5b field 6b
1    1-1       1-2a      1-3a      1-4a      1-5a     null     null
2    2-1       1-2a      1-3a      1-4a      1-5a     null     null 
3    3-1       1-2a      1-3a      1-4a      1-5a     null     null
4    4-1       1-2a      1-3a      1-4a      1-5a     null     null
5    5-1       1-2b      1-3b      1-4b      null     null     null
6    6-1       1-2b      1-3b      1-4b      null     1-5b     1-6b
7    7-1       1-2b      1-3b      1-4b      null     1-5b     1-6b
8    8-1       1-2b      1-3b      1-4b      null     1-5b     1-6b
9    9-11       1-2b      1-3b      1-4b      null     1-5b     1-6b
```

I have match to get all the columns with inner join  but I couldn't manage to get the results I ma looking for, any ideas about how can be obtained this? I have check here but I couldn't find any answer, also I have tried with coalescence but doesn't get the result I am expecting.

This is the type of query where I get all the fields for each table so a lot  of fields that are repeated.

```
SELECT t1.pk,
           t2.field 1ab,
        t2.field 1ab... t3.field 5b...
       FROM table 1 t1
         LEFT JOIN table b t2 ON t1.pk::text = t2.pk::text
         LEFT JOIN ocod t3 ON t3.pk::text = t1.pk::text
      GROUP BY
    t1.pk,
           t2.field 1ab,
        t2.field 1ab...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned something on this one. In your example, I don't see how table t1 relates to desired results. The desired results seem to be only a combination of t2 and t3. I got the kernel of the solution from this [Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179961/203856) which uses a [NATURAL JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html#NATURAL).

First create the tables:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    PK1     text,
    field_1 text,
    field_2 text,
    field_3 text,
    field_4 text,
    field_5 text
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
('1', '1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '1-4', '1-5'), 
('2', '2-1', '2-2', '2-3', '2-4', '2-5'),
('3', '3-1', '3-2', '3-3', '3-4', '3-5'), 
('4', '4-1', '4-2', '4-3', '4-4', '4-5'),
('5', '5-1', '5-2', '5-3', '5-4', '5-5');

CREATE TABLE t2 (
       PK1       text,
    field_1ab text,
    field_2ab text,
    field_3ab text,
    field_4ab text,
    field_5a  text
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
('1',  '1-1a',  '1-2a',  '1-3a',  '1-4a',  '1-5a'), 
('2',  '2-1a',  '2-2a',  '2-3a',  '2-4a',  '2-5a'),
('3',  '3-1a',  '3-2a',  '3-3a',  '3-4a',  '3-5a'), 
('4',  '4-1a',  '4-2a',  '4-3a',  '4-4a',  '4-5a'),
('5',  '5-1a',  '5-2a',  '5-3a',  '5-4a',  '5-5a');

CREATE TABLE t3 (
    PK1       text,
    field_1ab text,
    field_2ab text,
    field_3ab text,
    field_4ab text,
    field_5b  text,
    field_6b  text
);

INSERT INTO t3 VALUES
('6', '1-1b', '1-2b', '1-3b', '1-4b', '1-5b', '1-6b'), 
('7', '2-1b', '2-2b', '2-3b', '2-4b', '2-5b', '2-6b'),
('8', '3-1b', '3-2b', '3-3b', '3-4b', '3-5b', '3-6b'), 
('9', '4-1b', '4-2b', '4-3b', '4-4b', '4-5b', '4-6b'),
('10', '5-1b', '5-2b', '5-3b', '5-4b', '5-5b', '5-6b');

COMMIT;
```

And now for the query. It seems that if you do a NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN, PostgreSQL will try to combine as many columns as possible.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (t2 NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN t3)
ORDER BY pk1::int
```

which gives

| pk1 | field_1ab | field_2ab | field_3ab | field_4ab | field_5a | field_5b | field_5b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1a | 1-2a | 1-3a | 1-4a | 1-5a | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 2 | 2-1a | 2-2a | 2-3a | 2-4a | 2-5a | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 3 | 3-1a | 3-2a | 3-3a | 3-4a | 3-5a | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 4 | 4-1a | 4-2a | 4-3a | 4-4a | 4-5a | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 5 | 5-1a | 5-2a | 5-3a | 5-4a | 5-5a | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 6 | 1-1b | 1-2b | 1-3b | 1-4b | [NULL] | 1-5b | 1-6b |
| 7 | 2-1b | 2-2b | 2-3b | 2-4b | [NULL] | 2-5b | 2-6b |
| 8 | 3-1b | 3-2b | 3-3b | 3-4b | [NULL] | 3-5b | 3-6b |
| 9 | 4-1b | 4-2b | 4-3b | 4-4b | [NULL] | 4-5b | 4-6b |
| 10 | 5-1b | 5-2b | 5-3b | 5-4b | [NULL] | 5-5b | 5-6b |

Comment: It is slightly misleading to say *NATURAL JOIN without ON clause*.; it implies you could have an ON clause. NATURAL specifies the on clause as all matching column names and the ON clause **cannot be specified**.

Comment: @Belayer, you're right. Answer edited to remove any mention of ON clause.

Comment: @bfris I didnt add the column for the first table my mistake. I have edited the question so it is, for example geometry.. Thanks

Comment: @bfris I have accepted your answer it wasn't exactly but it really help me to point in some direction. Thanks